# How long time period does the .xsession-errors log file cover?

Tags: linux, x11, logs

**I have a hard time understanding how long time period my `.xsession-errors` file covers.** There's also a `.xsession-errors.old` and taking a quick look it seems there's one file for each time [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) was started? Is that correct?

Comment: It will depend on your log-rotation policy. It may not be time dependent.

Comment: The .xsession-errors file isn’t normally rotated since it lives in a user’s home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it depends on the distro, but on RHEL and Fedora, the file created in your home directory is created during each login, and if it already exists, it is moved to the .old file, overwriting the file if it exists.  It is used for the lifetime of the login session and closed when you log out.

Comment: This seems to be the case on Ubuntu as well.